# Error Pushing To My Own Stack in Assembly Masm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, masm

I'm new to assembly. I've been doing it a few months. I'm getting an error that crashes my program when I try to push a value onto my own stack array. The error says, "Access Violation Writing Location". I have stepped through it with the debugger and found nothing. So, I placed the code that was generating the error at the beginning of my program just to see if some other code (just reading from a file so far) might have caused it. I still get the error. Please help me, I have no idea what's going on. Here is my code:

```
 .data
 myStack DWORD 30 DUP(?)
 top DWORD $
 val DWORD 5

 .code
 mov esi, OFFSET myStack 
 mov eax, val
 add esi, top 
 sub esi, 4              
 mov [esi], eax   ;this is where it crashes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's an overriding reason why your stack *must* work like the processor's stack (i.e. the "top" grows down), it's much easier to do this with the "top" towards the end of the allocated buffer. The reason is that you don't have to think backwards to do it. The stack becomes just like any other buffer. You add the first item at the first position, and grow towards the end of your allocated buffer.

"Push" is a matter of adding an item to the next available position. "Pop" is a matter of removing from the highest used position.

Note that efficiency has nothing to do with my argument. Either way, you do the same amount of work. It's just easier to think about, because the stack is implemented like any other array-type structure: the first item you add goes to the first (lowest-numbered) address, etc. It's just a buffer that you access in LIFO order.

If you implement it as I suggest:

```
.data
myStack DWORD 30 DUP(?)
top DWORD myStack
val DWORD 5

.code

MyPush:
    // call with EAX containing the value you want to store
    mov esi,[top]
    mov [esi],eax
    add esi,4
    mov [top],esi
    ret

MyPop:
    // returns the value on the top of the stack in EAX
    mov esi,[top]
    sub esi,4
    mov eax,[esi]
    mov [top],esi
    ret
```

Comment: I think my professor would count off if I did it that way. Then it wouldn't be a traditional stack. I got it all worked now, though. Just a few bugs to contend with. Thanks, @Jim Mischel!

Comment: I think what tripped me up was that I've never accessed an array without loading it somehow. I mean, I knew it was going off somewhere else in memory but couldn't figure out why at first. It all makes sense now.

Comment: @lisabits: Don't confuse the *implementation* of your stack with the *interface*. A stack is an abstract data type to which you can add items. When you remove an item, you always get the most recently added item. How you implement it really doesn't matter. Whether the collection of items grows "up" or "down" in your buffer, or you somehow store them randomly is irrelevant. All that matters is that it returns items in the proper order. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29

Comment: I'm not confusing it with anything. I already finished the program and turned it in. All I'm saying is that's the way my professor told us to do it so he'll probably count off if I don't do it that way. I've had him count off for less insignificant things than that.@Jim Mischel... Why does Stack Overflow keep deleting my tags when I put them at the front of the comment? I see that it didn't do that to you. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it grows *down*, typical of microprocessor-based stacks, then to put something onto the stack:

1. Decrement the stack pointer
2. Move the value to what the stack pointer points to

And to take something off the stack:

1. Retrieve what the stack pointer points to
2. Increment the stack pointer

When you sum `top` to `myStack`, you're going to get an address that's way off somewhere else, probably outside of your program space. The `top` itself *is* already the address of the top of your stack without having to add anything to it.

So in your case, `top` is already the top of the stack. So your initial stack pointer should be `top`:

```
 .data
 myStack DWORD 30 DUP(?)
 top DWORD $
 val DWORD 5

.code
 mov esi, OFFSET top    ; Initialize the stack pointer
 mov eax, val           ; Load a value into eax
 sub esi, 4             ; push eax onto the stack
 mov [esi], eax
```

In the above, the first subtraction of 4 from the "stack pointer" (which is initially `top`) will yield `top - 4` which is the last 4-byte space in your `myStack` area.

To pop a value off of the stack:

```
mov eax, [esi]
add esi, 4
```

Alternatively, you could have set `top` differently, and then your code would work. But it's slightly more elaborate:

```
.data
 myStack DWORD 30 DUP(?)
 top DWORD $-myStack           ; the value here is current location minus myStack
 val DWORD 5

 .code
 mov esi, OFFSET myStack        ; Setup the stack pointer
 add esi, top 
 mov eax, val                   ; get value in eax
 sub esi, 4                     ; push eax          
 mov [esi], eax
```

Comment: Ahhhh! Ok, thank you so much, @lurker! This is my first time using $ so I was confused.So I never have to load myStack?

Comment: @lisabits The `$` just means the current program counter. So `top` points to a copy of its own address. In this context, it really doesn't matter what value `top` points to since you're using the label to represent the location past the end of your stack.

Comment: @lisabits, your code would have worked if you had `top DWORD $-myStack` instead of just `top DWORD $`.

Comment: yeah I understand that $ is current address. Just somehow I got confused when learning about it. I'm guessing that I was thinking $ by itself was doing $-myStack. I got the two mixed up apparently. And it's almost finals time so, you know, haha. My brain is about gone. Thanks!!

Comment: @lisabits if you find my answer acceptable, I'd be much obliged if you could mark it as "accepted". :)

Comment: I tried yesterday. I have to have 15 reputation to give an up-vote and I only have 12 so far. I'm sorry, @lurker! I really wanted to give it to ya! :)

Comment: @lisabits, yes for upvote that's true. But you can click the check mark to accept the answer (assuming you do accept it :)). And JimMischel is right in his response: a stack doesn't have to grow down. :)

Comment: Oh, I see! I'm new, heh. :) @lurker

Comment: @lisabits no worries. SO has a few little tidbits like that one finally catches on to.

Comment: You guys don't know my professor though, haha. He will count off for the most insignificant things. I'm probably going to have to actually drop this class when I've worked so hard. He is one of those ridiculous hard asses.@lurker